# We have $20$ students and $15$ lessons. In every lesson, one student is randomly picked and asked a question. Find expected value and variance.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation, variance

There are $20$ students and $15$ lessons. In each lesson, one student is randomly picked and asked a question by the teacher. Find expected value of amount of students asked a question during the 15 lessons and find its variance.

If $X$ is random variable representing number of students asked, then I guess to find $\mathbf{E}X$ we have to write something like $X=X_1+X_2+\dots$, but I cannot find some smart way to define those $X_i$, so a hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For the expected value, wouldn't it be simpler to compute the probability that exactly $k$ distinct students are asked a question, $1\le k\le 15$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Associate to any student $i\in\{1, ..., 20\}$ a random variable $X_i$ which counts the number of times the student $i$ has been asked a question during the $15$ lessons.
The $X_i's$ each follow a binomial law of parameters $n=15$, $p=1/20$.

Then the random variable counting the number of different students that were asked at least one question is
$X=1_{X_i\ge 1} + ... + 1_{X_{20}\ge 1}$

i.e., $\mathbb{E}(X)=P(X_1\ge 1) + ... + P(X_{20}\ge 1)$
$= 20(1-(19/20)^{15})$

- EDIT 1: To compute the variance, we can no longer use the above decomposition for the $X_i$'s are not pairwise independent (we have $\sum_i X_i=15$).

Let's now compute the probabilities $P(X=k)$, for $k\in\{1, ..., 15\}$.
We have $\left(20\atop{k}\right)$ choices of $k$ students among the class.
For such a choice, let's count the number of possibilities that these $k$ students are asked at least once a question (and only these students).
This amounts to count the number of surjection from $\{1, ..., 15\}$ to a set of $k$ elements, which is (after searching on Google)
$S_{15,k}=\sum_{i=0}^{k} (-1)^{k-i}\left(k\atop{i}\right)i^{15}$.

As we have $(20)^{15}$ possible choices in total, this gives
$$P(X=k)=\frac{1}{20^{15}}\left(20\atop{k}\right)\sum_{i=0}^{k} (-1)^{k-i}\left(k\atop{i}\right)i^{15}$$

We can check that it works trivially for $k=1$, and it's in fact not such a surprising formula. To count the number of surjections, we have to count all the functions (i.e., $k^{15}$) and remove the functions that take values in a stricly smaller subset (for all $1\le i<k$, we have $\left(k\atop{i}\right)$ such subsets), which amounts to subtract $\left(k\atop{i}\right)i^{15}$ functions, but we have to take care of the sub-subsets that could be subtracted twice, hence the power $(-1)^{k-i}$ ...

Given this formula, we can now compute the variance (to be continued ...)

- EDIT 2: Let's try to prove, using the explicit formula for $P(X=k)$, that
  $\mathbf{E}(X)=20(1-(\frac{19}{20}^{15})$.
  We have
  $$\sum_{k=1}^{15}kP(X=k)=
  \frac{1}{20^{15}}\sum_{k=1}^{15}k\left(20\atop{k}\right)\sum_{i=0}^{k} (-1)^{k-i}\left(k\atop{i}\right)i^{15}$$
  $$=\sum_{i=1}^{15}(\frac{i}{20})^{15}\sum_{k=i}^{15}k\left(20\atop{k}\right) (-1)^{k-i}\left(k\atop{i}\right)
  $$
  I believe that there must be some way to prove that this sum is equal to $20(1-(\frac{19}{20})^{15})$, which is just
  $$\sum_{k=0}^{14}(\frac{19}{20})^k=\sum_{k=0}^{14}(1-\frac{1}{20})^k$$
  $$=\sum_{k=1}^{15}\sum_{i=1}^k (-1)^{k-i}(\frac{1}{20})^{k-i}\left(k-1\atop{i-1}\right)$$
  $$=\sum_{k=1}^{15}\sum_{i=1}^k (\frac{1}{20})^{k-i}\left(k\atop{i}\right)\frac{i}{k}$$

Wolfram shows the result is the same ($=\frac{17586872970125200000}{1638400000000000000}$), and I believe that proving the formal equality will help us to compute the variance in an elegant way.

For the value of the variance, once again using Wolfram and the exact value for $P(X=k)$, we get
$Var(X)=\frac{4426364363247399877754480594066706599}{20^{28}}\approx 1,64895$.
But I still hope for something less horrible !

Comment: But you forgot to enforce the constraint $\sum_{i=1}^{20} X_i = 15$...
This version works when every student has a chance to be asked one question per lesson, not when exactly one student is asked one question per lesson.

Comment: You're right, my $X_i$'s as defined are not independent. But we don't need independence to use the linearity of expected value.

Comment: Congrats, you made me bug. Linearity still holds indeed, the law for one student should be binomial, but I am nearly convinced the parameter of the binomail change for each student above $1$, if it even remains a binomial. Otherwise you've found a way to cheat the non-independence of the $X_i$'s, and it'd be as good as saying the $X_i$'s are actually independant.

Comment: From the point of view of one student, the probability of being asked a question at each lesson is still $1/20$, and the $15$ choices are independent. So all the $X_i$'s are a sum of $15$ independent Bernoulli trials of parameter $p=1/20$, i.e., are Binomial of parameters $(15, 1/20)$.

Comment: But that is only from the point of view of **one** student, this breaks when you consider the whole class. If you focus on one lesson, student 1 has probability $1/20$ to be asked a question. If he is asked a question, all other students then have probability $0$ to be asked a question, and bernouilli doesn't hold. If student 1 is not asked a question, then student 2 has probability $1/19$ to be asked a question, etc. Then repeat for each lesson. You don't get a binomial in the end, except for student 1, because you must consider the non-independance.

Comment: You're telling that $X_i^{(k)}$ and $X_j^{(k)}$ are not independent, if $i\neq j $ and $k\in\{1, ..., 15\}$ (where I put $X_i^{(k)}=1$ if student $i$ is asked a question at lesson $k$, 0 otherwise). I agree with it, but this doesn't mean that $X_i^{(k)}$ and $X_i^{(k')}$ are not independent for $k\neq k'$ (I claim they are).

Comment: You could argue I introduce order in a non-ordered set, so let me put this another way. Assume a teacher holds 15 individual lessons with 20 students (total $15\times 20$ individual lessons), and ask the student a question with probability $1/20$, where everything is independent. There, you get a your binomials.
The teacher then realize he can just have class with all $20$ students together, and decide to independently ask each student 1 question/lesson with probability $1/20$, this is the same binomials. In OP's question the situation is different.

Comment: $X_i^{(k)}$ and $X_i^{(k')}$ should be independent. I also assume them to be independent. But the non-independence of $X_i^k$ and $X_j^k$ means you cannot model them with Bernouilli trials.

Comment: Why not ? It's like rolling a dice with 20 faces, 15 times. At the end you count the number of times each of the 20 faces appeared, and we focus on the number of different faces that actually appeared. I claim that for each face and each roll, the probability that the face appears is 1/20.

Comment: Your dice description is correct, your way of counting isn't: these are not binomials/Bernouilli trials. The binomial model do not prevent you from having $X_i^k=1=X_j^k$, with $i\neq j$. That would mean your dice landed on 2 faces simultaneously.

Comment: You made a typo, there are $k^{20}$ functions total, not $20^k$. Thanks to you I also noticed I made another error in my computation of $P(X=k)$...

Comment: Yes I made several typos indeed (the power of i wasn't correct as well)..It's now corrected, I hope.

Comment: OK let simplify: roll a dice twice and denote $(i,j)$ the result. For the face 1, the possibilities that 1 has appeared at least once are $(1,1)$, $(1,2)$, $(1,3)$, $(1,4)$, $(1,5)$, $(1,6)$, $(2,1)$, $(3,1)$, $(4,1)$, $(5,1)$, $(6,1)$: $11$ possibilities, so $P(X_1\ge 1)=11/36=1-(\frac{5}{6})^2$. Now look at face 2: the possibilities that it appeared at least once are $(2,1)$, $(2,2)$, $(2,3)$, $(2,4)$, $(2,5)$, $(2,6)$, $(1,2)$, $(3,2)$, $(4,2)$,$(5,2)$ and $(6,2)$: still $11$ possibilities.You see it's the same for any face, and the $X_i$'s follow a binomial $\mathcal{B}(2,1/6)$

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Not sure what I was confused about yesterday. Let me apologise for my stubbornness and misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2):

The trick to a lot of problems about discrete random variables is to write them as a sum of indicator random variables and exploit symmetries.  This is an example of such a problem.  Since you're interested in second moments, we just need to understand what happens to any two students at a time.

There's nothing special about the numbers 20 and 15 here.  Let's say there are $s$ students and $\ell$ lessons.  Later on we'll plug in $s = 20, \ell = 15$.

Let $X_i$ be the number of times that student $i$ is asked a question.  Let $Y_i = 1_{X_i \ge 1}$ be 1 if student $i$ is asked a question at least once, and 0 otherwise.  Let $Y = Y_1 + \cdots + Y_s$ be the total number of students asked a question; we're trying to find $E(Y)$.

Now $E(Y) = E(Y_1) + \cdots + E(Y_s)$ since expectation is linear, and then $E(Y) = s E(Y_1)$ by symmetry - all the students are the same.  $E(Y_1)$ is the probability that student 1 is asked at least one question; this is $1-(1-1/s)^\ell$.  Therefore $E(Y) = s (1-(1-1/s)^\ell)$.  With the particular numbers you asked about, this is $20 \times (1 - (19/20)^{15}) \approx 10.73$.

To find the variance is a bit trickier.  Of course $Var(Y) = E(Y^2) - E(Y)^2$.  We know $E(Y)$ and thus $E(Y)^2$.  Now the thing to do here is to write $Y = Y_1 + \cdots + Y_s$, and thus we get

$$E(Y^2) = E( (Y_1 + \cdots + Y_s)^2 ) = E(Y_1^2 + \cdots + Y_s^2) + E(Y_1 Y_2 + Y_1 Y_3 + \cdots + Y_{s-1} Y_s)$$

where the first term has the squares of each of $Y_1$ through $Y_s$, and the second term has all the terms of the form $Y_j Y_k$ where $j \not = k$.  Now we can rewrite this as

$$ s E(Y_1^2) + s(s-1) E(Y_1 Y_2) $$

by symmetry.  Every student is the same so $E(Y_j^2)$ doesn't depend on $j$, and every pair of students is the same so $E(Y_j Y_k)$ doesn't depend on $j, k$ as long as $j$ and $k$ aren't the same.

Let's turn to $E(Y_1^2)$.  Since $Y_1$ is an indicator random variable it's always 0 or 1, so $Y_1 = Y_1^2$; thus $E(Y_1^2) = E(Y_1) = (1-(1-1/s)^\ell).$

Now, what is $E(Y_1 Y_2)$?  $Y_1 Y_2$ is 1 if both students 1 and 2 get asked a question, and zero otherwise.  This is the tricky part.  We need the principle of inclusion-exclusion:

$$P(Y_1 = 1 \hbox{ or } Y_2 = 1) = P(Y_1 = 1) + P(Y_2 = 1) - P(Y_1 = 1 \hbox{ and } Y_2 = 1)$$

which we can rearrange to get

$$P(Y_1 = 1 \hbox{ and } Y_2 = 1) =  P(Y_1 = 1) + P(Y_2 = 1) - P(Y_1 = 1 \hbox{ or } Y_2 = 1)$$

Of course $P(Y_1 = 1) = E(Y_1) = 1-(1-1/s)^\ell$ and $P(Y_2 = 1) = E(Y_2) = 1-(1-1/s)^\ell$.  And we can see that $P(Y_1 = 1 \hbox{ or } Y_2 = 1) = 1-(1-2/s)^\ell$, since $(1-2/s)^\ell$ is the probability that neither $1$ nor $2$ ever gets asked a question.  Thus we have

$$E(Y_1 Y_2) = P(Y_1 = 1 \hbox{ and } Y_2 = 1) = 2 (1-(1-1/s)^\ell) - (1-(1-2/s)^\ell)$$

and with the particular numbers you asked about, this is $2 (1 - (19/20)^{15}) - (1 - (18/20)%{15}) \approx 0.2793$.

So we can finally put everything together to get

$$E(Y^2) = s (1-(1-1/s)^\ell) + s(s-1) [2 (1-(1-1/s)^\ell) - (1-(1-2/s)^\ell)] $$

and thus

$$Var(Y) = s (1-(1-1/s)^\ell) + s(s-1) [2 (1-(1-1/s)^\ell) - (1-(1-2/s)^\ell)] - (s (1-(1-1/s)^\ell))^2 $$

(which can probably be simplified a bit).  If you plug in $s = 20, \ell = 15$ you get about $1.64895$ ,the same numerical answer as Yoel.

Comment: Dear Michael, as you can see I had the same approach as yours, but couldn't find that very simple way to express $P(\{X_i\ge 1\} \cap \{X_j\ge 1\})$ that you did and which is totally exact (I tried to compute it by combinatorial means, using the exact value of $P(X\ge k)$, which turned out to be a tricky summation). Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning how to define $X_i$, I can see two "bad" ways to do it:

**Bad way 1**

\begin{cases}
X_i=1 & \text{if at least $i$ different students are asked a question}\\
X_i=0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
then you'd have to compute the expected value of a sum of non independant random variables, and I don't recommend it.

**Bad way 2**

\begin{cases}
X_i=1 & \text{if the $i$-th student was asked a question}\\
X_i=0 & \text{if the $i$-th student was not asked a question}
\end{cases}
and once again, you end up with non independant random variables.

Right now I don't see other ways, but I'm not convinced there's a good way to do this with $X=\sum X_i$.
Instead consider the following.

**Another way (detailed because it turns out I'm bad at this)**

If we can compute the probabilities $P(X=k)$,
then $\mathbb EX=\sum_{k=1}^{15} kP(X=k)$.
To get $P(X=k)$, go see the edit section of Yoël's answer.

### EDIT:

Corrected the "alternative way" computation after SekstusEmpiryk's remark
New version after Yoël pointed out another error
Removed old and false computation of $P(X=k)$

Comment: That's not exactly correct. $(k/20)^{15}$ is probability that only students from given $k$-elements subgroup can be asked. But that does not guarantee that all of them are asked.

Comment: @SekstusEmpiryk true, editing...

Comment: I think your computation of $P(X=k)$ doesn't hold. Take $k=1$, then your result is 15 times too big. In general, I feel like you're counting several times each combination with this approach (and I don't see any simple formula for $P(X=k)$ for the moment).

Comment: @Yoël Looks like I made another mistake while counting the multiplicity tied to the order of the lessons... guess another edit is incoming. Thanks for the heads up.